# Getting the ruby exec syntax right

Tags: ruby, exec

I want to execute a variable shell command through ruby. I am a ruby beginner. I had the command working without variables, but when I tried to set variables the exec command doesn't work and the script stops running.
All 3 variables hold Strings.

The print is working fine, but exec not.

```
print "#{jobserv}" + options[:machines] + " -c touch #{noautooffPath} \n"

exec('"#{jobserv}" + options[:machines] + " -c touch #{noautooffPath}"')
```

What do i have to do to make the exec right or to get more hints by the system on how to correct this?

jobserv hold a path to an executable file plus options, options[:machines] holds a parameter I give to the last option flag of jobserv.

Comment: _"All 3 variables hold Strings"_ – can you be more specific? The string values seem to be relevant.

Comment: BTW, why do you use `" + options[:machines] + "` instead of `#{options[:machines]}` for the middle part?

Comment: Because I am a ruby beginner and have c/p-ed this from another working script I wrote.

Comment: Remember that `"#{x}"` is almost always better expressed as `x` or, in rare cases, `x.to_s`. There's no reason to use string interpolation on a single string value.

Comment: Another thing to note is capital letters have specific meaning in Ruby and are reserved for `ClassName` and `CONSTANT_NAME` situations. Methods and variables should be `lower_case` only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, check you want [`exec`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-exec). Several other options, like [`system`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-system), are more common choices for running a shell command. (Specifically, if `exec` is successful, the Ruby script will stop executing and be *replaced* by the command it executes; the rest of the script will never be run.)

You seem to have an extra layer of single quotes in your exec call. You probably want something closer to this:

```
exec("#{jobserv}" + options[:machines] + " -c touch #{noautooffPath}")
```

(assuming the `print` is showing the value you want)

---

In general, it's safer to avoid the single-string shell form, and pass all the argument individually. That might look more like this:

```
exec("#{jobserv}#{options[:machines]}", "-c", "touch", noautooffPath)
```

or:

```
exec(jobserv, options[:machines], "-c", "touch", noautooffPath)
```

(depending on whether `jobserv` and `options[:machines]` are expected to combine. And it'd look different again if any of those are expected to themselves contain a full multi-argument command invocation.)

Comment: Is there a missing space between `jobserv` and `options[:machines]`? Either way, if it's not working, you should be getting an at-least-somewhat-useful error message.

Comment: I'd focus on that symptom, then... change the command you're running to something that'll definitely fail (I'd try both `"zzz"` and `"bash -c zzz"`, which should each fail differently), and track until you can see those errors. Until then, it's unclear whether ruby is failing to run the target command, or the target command is being started but then itself failing silently.

Comment: Don't forget its **very important** to properly escape any and all variable parameters that are being passed in if using string interpolation or concatenation to compose a single command. [`shellescape`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellescape) can handle this. The second method where each argument is specified individually is safer and recommended in this case.